# Include file containing Constant Buffers - what about the registers?

Tags: include, hlsl

in hlsl, we can use `#include "somefile"` just like in C.
I would like to declare my Constant Buffers only once and include them in multiple shaders. But what about the registers? In some files a Constant Buffer is set to b0, in others it is b4. What is the best practice including files here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can #define the register names before including your header, and in the header file you can use them like regular preprocessor tokens — instead of having `register(b0)` in the header, you can type, for instance, `register(B_CAMERA)` in it, and before including, `#define B_CAMERA b0`.

Be careful, however, if you want to just pass the register number like 0 rather than the entire register name like `b0` since the HLSL preprocessor handles ## concatenation [slightly differently than the C preprocessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-appendix-pre-define-2), and there are also [differences in how the shader model 5 and below and how the shader model 6 compilers](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/issues/1005) expand it.